# How to insert PHP values into Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Javascript:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 5;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = " <br><select name='vehicle[]' id = 'vehicle'><option value = ''>Vehicle "+ (counter + 1) +"</option><option value = '.$brand.' '.$name.'>'.$brand.' '.$name.'</option>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

PHP/HTML:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/addinput.js"></script>
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="services.php" onsubmit="return valid()">
    <br><br><br><center>
    <table class="form" border=1> 
    <tr>
    <td class="head" colspan="2"     >Select Vehicle:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ></tr>
    <tr>
    <td  colspan="2"  class="info">
    <div id="dynamicInput">
    <br><select name = "vehicle[]" id = "vehicle1"> 
    <option value = "">Vehicle 1</option>';
        include_once "vehicledbconnect.php";
        $queryveh = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicletbl");
        while($fetch_2 = mysql_fetch_array($queryveh)) {
        $brand = $fetch_2['vehbrand'];
        $name = $fetch_2['vehname'];
        echo '<option value = "'.$brand.' '.$name.'">'.$brand.' '.$name.'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input type="button" value="Add another vehicle" onClick="addInput(\'dynamicInput\');"></div>';
```

Hi. Is it possible to insert PHP values in a javascript? I have a program here that if the customer click the submit button (echo '), a new drop-down form will appear. And I want the drop down form to contain all of the values of the query ($queryveh = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicletbl");). In my default drop-down form, all values of the query are shown. Please help me guys. I am desperate for an answer. Javascript is my weakness. Thanks a lot.

edit:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = " <br><select name='vehicle[]' id = 'vehicle'><option value = ''>Vehicle "+ (counter + 1) +"</option>" + "<?php include 'vehicledbconnect.php'; $queryveh = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM vehicletbl'); while($fetch_2 = mysql_fetch_array($queryveh)) { $brand = $fetch_2['vehbrand']; $name = $fetch_2['vehname']; <option value = '.$brand.' '.$name.'>'.$brand.' '.$name.'</option> }?>";
```

Can this be the solution? I've tried but it's not working, if this can be the solution, maybe there's only something wrong with my code here.

Comment: I would look at using jQuery and AJAX.  You can call your php call and return JSON values.  Then parse those values and addthem to your dropdown list.

Comment: @JeffV I dont know how to use AJAX and Jquery.

Comment: If i understand correctly, on form submit you want to add a new drop down with all the entries from the `vehicletbl`, AND keep the original drop down WITH the newly added entries via the `Add another vehicle` button. Is that it ?

Comment: @danishgoel 'If i understand correctly, on form submit you want to add a new drop down with all the entries from the vehicletbl' AND after adding a new drop down, all the values from the original drop down will be available and can be selected by the user in the new drop down after clicking the Add another vehicle button.

Comment: Why not just populate the dropdown box when the page is generated?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to retrieve values from a server from javascript is to use AJAX.

Well you can do it without AJAX if you don't mind a page refresh, but I don't think that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a jQuery load function. This is the simplest example I can muster up for you.

You will need to download jQuery (http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) and include it in your html header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can make a simple function to call; either as a onclick or onchange depending on your preference.

```
function reloadDropDown()
    {
        document.getElementById('dynamicInput').innerHTML = 'Loading ...';
        var v_name = document.formname.elementname.value;
        $('#dynamicInput').load("dropdownload.php", { vehicle_name : v_name });
    }
```

Let me go through this. dropdownload.php would have your '$queryveh' made drop down code. Javascript basically plonks whatever happens in dropdownload.php on to a div with the id 'dynamicInput' When javascript loads dropdownload.php it sends via POST a variable by the name vehicle_name which you can use as $_POST['vehicle_name'] within dropdownload.php.

So, dropdownload.php may look something like this.

```
<?php
$queryveh = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicletbl WHERE vehname = '{$_POST['vehicle_name']}'");

// collect the data and put it in to an Array I like to do this so I can check the array to make sure it has something in it if not return an error message but I will skip that for the purpose of this explanation.

while($ucRow = mysql_fetch_array($queryveh, MYSQL_ASSOC)) array_push($resultsArray, $ucRow);
?>

<select name = "vehicle[]" id = "vehicle1"> 
<?php
foreach ($resultsArray as $fetch_row){ 
    ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $fetch_row['vehbrand'].' '.$fetch_row['vehname'].'; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_row['vehbrand'].' '.$fetch_row['vehname']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
?>
```

I'm not entirely certain on the end result you are after but that is a basic jQuery ajax call. If you can grasp that, you are half way to a truly dynamic web page / app with some further practice with this area. Hope that gives you a direction to go in :)

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript gets evaluated on the client ..so like Html ..so it is to be used the same way.

-> yes, you just use php in your javascript as long as its defined to be evaluated by php first (usually within a .php file)

edit:

just to clarify, if you want to get values within javascript from the server by php.. you need to have a look at what danishgoel said: Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript) ..see - since Rikudo Sennin disrespected the link, another http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest ..or even better have a look at a javascript framework that does most of the stuff for you (f.e. jQuery)

Comment: honestly? ..didn't know - I'll look into it

Comment: @Rikudo: that is sad.  W3Schools, despite misinformation (which everything has) is still what many people use.  Promote JS didn't take off because it's designed for programmers, not for beginners.  It's page design (interface) wasn't what beginners need, and that's what W3Schools really caters to.

Comment: ..have to agree, I know quite some people that use it ..I myself often do just a quick search and if the result-page contains sufficient code/infos, its commonly used. ..I thinks its up to everyone to sort out whats wrong information, which is (unfortunately for newbies) to be found almost everywhere on the web.

Comment: I'm afraid I still have to disagree, if it were "some misinformation" then I would have looked away, but since it's actively misleading, and rarely bother to correct their errors, I still discourage the use of it for progammers of any level. There are plenty of easy solutions to help their website, such as wikifying it, or having a serious error submission system.